# Python, passing variable from function to class NameError: name 'var1' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to pass a variable to class that was defined earlier. But it gives me an error, why? How can i fix it? I don't want to copy class inside every function that will use it.

```
class print_it():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        print(str(var1), str(var2))

def yolo():
    var1 = 1
    var2 = 2

    print_it(var1,var2)

yolo()
```

The only workable solution for me was putting class inside the function, defining variables globally doesn't work since it doesn't take new values.
I've also tried this:

```
    pr = print_it()
    pr.var1(var1)
    pr.var2(var2)
```

Comment: Well your `__init__` takes `*args`. So there is no `var1` defined. Either change to `def __init__(self, var1, var2)` or do `self.var1 = args[0]`

Comment: "it gives me an error" isn't very informative. Why not say what that error is and give the full error traceback?

Comment: Tomerikoo
Thank you, with this example it works but with big one fails for some reason.

Comment: file.io/2yWi/download/XoB2kpVnqxWI Function print_orgs_from_file_gui(filer) and class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel) are in question. The same trick didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tomerikoo already mentioned, just change the `__init__` arguments. If you always only expect two variables like `var1` and `var2` then you can use this code:

```
class print_it:
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        print(str(var1), str(var2))

def yolo():
    var1 = 1
    var2 = 2

    print_it(var1,var2)

yolo()
```

Comment: Thank you it solved this specific problem, can you lookup at the bigger one?

Comment: https://www.file.io/2yWi/download/XoB2kpVnqxWI Function print_orgs_from_file_gui(filer) and  class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel) are in question. The same trick didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific problem in the link provided in the comment to my previous answer, you only need to change the `TableModel` class as follows:

```
class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, rows, headers):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self.rows = rows
        self.headers = headers

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.rows)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.headers)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role != Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()
        return self.rows[index.row()][index.column()]

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role != Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole or orientation != Qt.Orientation.Horizontal:
            return QVariant()
        return self.headers[section]
```

Let me know, if this is the result what you expect.